# UITableViewCell nil IBOutlets when UITableView is declared in nib

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nib

Firstly, sorry If something I say is wrong as this is my first attempt to work with nibs.

I have a UIViewController "MainVC" that gets Initialised with a nib file (I decided that because it is a popup and made more sense) and I want to embed another view controller "RenderersViewController" within a UIView. For doing that I do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let renderersVC = RenderersViewController(withRowHeight: 42)
    addChild(renderersVC)
    renderersVC.view.frame = renderersContainerView.bounds
    renderersContainerView.addSubview(renderersVC.view)
    renderersVC.didMove(toParent: self)

}
```

RenderersViewController is UIViewController that has a UITableView and it has a custom Initialisation and nib

[image]

```
init(withRowHeight rowHeight:CGFloat) {
    self.rowHeight = rowHeight

    super.init(nibName: "RendererVCNib", bundle: nil)

}
```

when the tableView in RenderersViewController didSet i Register a custom UITableViewCell that also has it's own nib.

```
@IBOutlet weak var renderersTableView: UITableView!{
    didSet{
        renderersTableView.register(RenderersTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mycell")
        renderersTableView.bounces = false
        renderersTableView.dataSource = self
        renderersTableView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

and in cellForIndex

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let rendererCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell", for: indexPath) as! RenderersTableViewCell

    if indexPath.row < rendererArray.count{

        let cpRendererItem = rendererArray[indexPath.row]

        //rendererCell.rendererNameLabel.text = cpRendererItem.friendlyName
        //rendererCell.rendererImageView.sd_setImage(with: cpRendererItem.iconUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"upnp_ic")!)

        rendererCell.rendererNameLabel.text = "HELLO"
        rendererCell.rendererImageView.image = UIImage(named:"upnp_ic")

    }

    return rendererCell

}
```

But it crashes because the IBOutlets are nil...
[image]

**RenderersTableViewCell Nib**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of registering the cell's class, you need to register the nib file, that is used to instantiate the cell:

```
@IBOutlet weak var renderersTableView: UITableView!{
    didSet{
        let nibFile = UINib(nibName: "cells_xib_file", bundle: nil)
        renderersTableView.register(nibFile, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mycell")
        renderersTableView.bounces = false
        renderersTableView.dataSource = self
        renderersTableView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Apart from that your xib file looks a little bit wrong. For a cell xib, it should have kind of `UITableViewCell` (fro your case `RenderersTableViewCell`) as a top view component in the hierarchy. Eventually you should get something similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HPl4.png).

Comment: Thank you for your answer now I am getting "  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (mycell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance' "

Comment: Yes, it's something i missed. In your storiboard the top object is a common view, but you need to make it kind of UITableViewCell (for your case RenderersTableViewCell) so the view hierarchy should look like this: https://i.imgur.com/TiKdxyy.png

Comment: Yeei!! With the picture I have seen it a little bit more clear! It does not crash now. I have always struggled to understand what file's owners means. If you attach the picture and a little bit the files owner's stuff i will accept it and upvote it...

Comment: @ReimondHill, edited :)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!!!:)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!!!:)